# Appending multiple files into a data frame using R

Tags: r, append, rbind

I am trying to append more than 10 000 files into a data frame in R. The first step in this job was to scrape files from

`for(i in 1:10000) { 
  assign(x = paste("data", i, sep = "_"), value = 
           readHTMLTable((paste("webaddress_page=", i, sep = '')),which=1)) 
}`

This works just fine, and I have 10 000 files, data_1-data_10000. However, I would like to append these files into a data.frame, but not sure how to proceed? Do I add another "data step", or maybe it is possible to do within the existing code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(plyr)

files <- data_1-data_10000

dat <- ldply(files, function(fn) data.frame(read.table(fn, header = FALSE)))
```

Make sure to read the options in `read.table` and fit to your data.

**EDIT**

Let's try this:

```
dat <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:10000) { 
    dat.pre <- readHTMLTable((paste("webaddress_page=", i, sep = '')), which=1)
    n <- max(length(dat), length(dat.pre))
    length(dat) <- n
    length(dat.pre) <- n
    dat <- cbind(dat, dat.pre) 
}
```

Comment: After 
fn <- data_1-data_3 i get
 Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : - not meaningful for factors

dat <- ldply(files, function(fn) data.frame(read.table(fn, header = FALSE)))
Error in inherits(.data, "split") : object 'files' not found
I am not sure what that means.

Comment: See edit, I made a wrong assign, sorry about that. Is `data_1-data_10000` a list of files?

Comment: No. Its not a list. I guess that is why files did not work. Since I am using ReadHTMLTable from library(XML) all the files are data.frames.

Comment: What do you get when you do `str()` on one of your files?

Comment: I get 
'data.frame': 10 obs. of  5 variables:
Everything inside is factors

Comment: See edit, let me know if it works. I suggest doing it only with `i in 1:10` at first. This will only work if all your files have the same number of observations and will bind them column-wise. To bind them row-wise use `rbind`.

Comment: Actually in ReadHTMLTable I can specifiy as.data.frame=FALSE, and that gives me a list, but when I: fn <- data_1-data_10000 I get another error message... Error in data_1 - data_10000 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Try the code after the EDIT. In the first piece of code you need a list of all the filenames. I erroneously assigned the "list" to `fn`, when it should've been assigned to `files`. The second block of code should work with data frames.

Comment: Thanks, but then i get Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Sorry about that, I had an extra parentheses at the end of `which=1)`

Comment: I should have seen that. Sorry. But still get error: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 10. I also got that when I tried to do this outside the loop.

Comment: See the edit, it's not very elegant, but should work.

Comment: I tweaked your code just a bit. Dat needed to have a specified col and row length. Also, I was looking for rbind. Works like a charm. Thanks!

    dat <- readHTMLTable("webaddress_page=1", which=1)
    for(i in 2:10000) { 
    dat.pre <- readHTMLTable((paste("webadress_page=", i, sep = '')),
                           ,which=1)
     dat <- rbind(dat, dat.pre) 
    }

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to upvote, or I would definitely do that. I just accepted. Thanks!